# getScript function not working - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I'm using `bootstrap-select` in my page.

at first time when the page loaded my `bootstrap-select` works fine. I loaded these libraries at the footer of my page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{URL::to('/').'/assets/frontend/'}}_js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{URL::to('/').'/assets/frontend/'}}_js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{URL::to('/').'/assets/frontend/'}}_js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

now user want to filter products and I use post ajax method:

```
function getPosts(page,brands,min_price,max_price) {
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            url: '?page=' + page+'&brands=' + brands + '&min_price=' + min_price + '&max_price=' + max_price ,
        }).done(function(data) {

            if(data == 'empty')
            {

            }else{

                $('.product-list').html(data);
                location.hash = page;

                var url_1 = '{{URL::to('/').'/assets/frontend/'}}_js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js';
                var url_2 = '{{URL::to('/').'/assets/frontend/'}}_js/bootstrap.min.js';
                var url_3 = '{{URL::to('/').'/assets/frontend/'}}_js/bootstrap-select.min.js';

                $.getScript(url_1);
                $.getScript(url_2);
                $.getScript(url_3);
            }

        }).fail(function() {
            if(brands != null)
            {
                getPosts(1,null,0,0);

            }else{

            }


        });
    }
```

my products will load in my page but `bootstrap-select` not work at all.

my html code:

```
 <select name="product-quantity"  class="form-control selectpicker" data-size="5">
...
```

`getScript` called but not work on my `select-option`:
[image]

Comment: `'{{URL::to('/').'/assets/frontend/'}}_js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js'` is not a valid string

Comment: because I'm using a framework it works fine. the result is: `var url_3 = 'http://localhost:8000/assets/frontend/_js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js‌​';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to re-insert the libraries. Once is enough.
You just need to run the script that initializes the select drop-down.

```js
else {

  $('.product-list').html(data);
  location.hash = page;
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();

}
```